# find a vector v having the same lenght with vector u?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can you please help with this question?

> **Q**uestion : find a vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that has the same length 
>    with vector $u= (1,0,-1)$ and makes an angle of $\frac{\pi}{3}$ with vector  $u$. How many such vectors are there?

Attempt :

The length of $u$ is $\sqrt{2}$, therefore vector $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,0,-1)$. Is that correct?
 How do I answer "*How many such vectors are there?*"

Comment: Well, that $\;\left\|u\right\|=\sqrt2\;$ , doesn't necessarily mean $\;v=\frac1{\sqrt2}u\;$ ....*unless* you can prove the angle between the two vectors indeed is $\;\frac\pi3\;$ ...and it isn't.

Comment: can you explain how to find a vector with an angle of pi/3 with u? thanks

Comment: $\mathbf u\cdot \mathbf v = \|u\|\|v\| \cos\theta$  

There is a set of vectors that with heads lying on a circle with $\mathbf v$ going through the center of the circle.

Comment: thanks, so the number of vectors will be a circle? we are in R^3, was it not supposed to be a sphere?

Comment: The number of vectors is infinite.  But that doesn't mean that you couldn't come up with a formula that would describe the complete set.  But, the question doesn't ask for the complete set.  The question is only asking for you to find one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\|u\|=\sqrt{2}$, hence assuming that $v=(x,y,z)$ form an angle of $60^\circ$ with $u$ and has the same length of $u$,
$$ \color{blue}{x^2+y^2+z^2=2},\qquad \langle u,v\rangle = \color{blue}{x-z} = \|u\|\|v\|\cos 60^{\circ} \color{blue}{= 1} $$
have to hold. These equations describe the intersection between a sphere centered at the origin and a plane through the origin, hence there is a whole circle of points $v$ fulfilling the wanted constrains.
$$ v=(1,1,0)$$
is just one of them.

Comment: can you explain how to get the vector v?

Comment: @matheu96: the vector**s** $v=(x,y,z)$ are given by the solutions of $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$ and $x-z=1$. $v=(1,1,0)$ is one of them.